# JAVA: How can we print the parameter value in console?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Class1:has a reusable function like this-

```java
public class Class1 {
    WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    public WebElement getElement(WebElement element) {
        wdw.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    }
}
```

Class2:

```
public class Class2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ge.getElement(login_button).click();
    }

}
```

Now how can I get "login_button" print in console (with some more message)if this element not present on page or timed out etc

I have tried:
Class1:

```
public class GetElement {

    WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    public WebElement getElement(WebElement element) {
        try {

            return wdw.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println(element);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

But printing this element gives this in console:

`Proxy element for: org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator@57250572` instead of

`login_button`

Comment: Use `System.out.println("Any string");`

Comment: You should check if `ge.getElement(login_button)` is null, after which refer to @OO7's comment

Comment: You can use `getText()` of `WebElement`. Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You have **WebElement** & want to print it's name, then you can use **getText()** method of **WebElement** interface. Look at this [WebElement - java.lang.String getText()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText()).

```
public class GetElement {

    WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        public WebElement getElement(WebElement element) {
            try {
                return wdw.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(element.getText());
            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is working for you? because I have already tried what you wrote above and it doesn't print ANYTHING.

Comment: Have u set any value attribute for button ? I don't have any idea how u want login_button on console ? Do u want name of button to be clicked & if not clicked then what should be there ?

Comment: it is defined like this `@FindBy(linkText = "Log In")
 private WebElement login_button;` So I want to print `syso(element+" found missing");` which will give `login_button found missing`

Comment: Look at `login button` in HTML document. Check if it has `value attribute`. Then u can use [WebElement - java.lang.String getAttribute("Attibute to be fetched")](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) to get value to be displayed on the button. Just like `element.getAttribute("value")`.

Comment: I know that, but question is how to print the parameter passed?